# python process exit or crash without clue

Tags: python, mysql, crash

Recently I've created a python script to retrieve data out from a log file and write into a mysql database. This script is suppose to be running 24 hours, but it crashes unexpectedly and I have no clue as to why.

How can I go about accessing the crash report?

My software specifications are.

- python version: 2.5.4
- MySQL-python-1.2.3c1

Comment: Maybe just have it dump stderr to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that a fatal internal error is not causing your issue you could register an [`atexit`](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) function to get some more information about the time and issue:

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def what_happened():
    # TODO: Implement this
    # get the time
    # get tracebacks via http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info
    #    and http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html
    #
    # Attempt to write all of the above to a file
```

If a fatal error or system event is causing the crash you may need to check your OS's help documentation to find other ways to trace the issue (the Event Viewer on Windows, `/var/logs` on Linux [although I'm sure there is a better way] and Console for Mac [as far as I understand it]).